# Extract a PDF417 barcode from the PDF and get its data using iTextSharp

Tags: itext, barcode

We are going to be emailing interactive PDFs to people, who will complete them and email them back. In the proof-of-concept, I am placing a PDF417 barcode image on the PDF using iTextSharp. The PDF contains some other images.

When the completed PDF is sent back to us, how to find and extract the barcode image from the PDF document?

And once we have the barcode image, how do we get the data that was set with `barcode.SetText(value)`?

Comment: Is the document you get back the modified version of the one you created? In any case, 100% sure solution is to extract the barcode image and then feed in to some barcode recognition tools. Creating barcode from text is a kind of one-way operation from the PDF point of view. You have to read barcodes to get their value and reading barcodes is not a part of iText functionality. You can do some dirty tricks like placing real barcode contents into metadata PDF or in other places and then read it from there, but this solution is prone to hacking and not 100% sure one.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure if iTextSharp had the feature.  Have found my way to ZXing.

Comment: Good choice. iText uses ZXing's one-way conversion from data to barcode image anyway. You are now using the other half of the ZXing library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 100% sure solution is to extract the barcode image and then feed in to some barcode recognition tools.

Creating barcode from text is a kind of one-way operation from the PDF point of view. You have to read barcodes to get their value and reading barcodes is not a part of iText functionality.

You can do some dirty tricks like placing real barcode contents into metadata PDF or in other places and then read it from there, but this solution is prone to hacking and not 100% sure one.

So to summarize, you have to use a third party tool to extract values from barcodes.

Comment: I've posted this is an answer to be able to mark other questions as duplicates of this one (if this answer gets upvoted or accepted any time)